# C# - Access File-Class in Windows 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xml, file, save

I've searched alot but I can't find a solution for my problem:

I'm writing an Windows 8.1 App and I've a Class, which I want to Serialize, because I want to store the Data from this Class.

But I can't access the File-Class, **Visual Studio still cannot recognize File as a class name**.

Here's my Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Windows.Storage;



namespace Password.Data
{
    class DataContainer
    {
        SortedDictionary<int, PasswordBox> Data { get; set; }
        public int Key { get; set; }

        public void Save(DataContainer a, string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataContainer));
            using (Stream s = File.OpenWrite(filename))
            {
                ser.Serialize(s, a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use the File-Class in this case? Or are there new Classes in order to tell my Stream that he has to write the data to file xy.

Or are there other ways to save a Dictionary?

Comment: Try making the class public.

Comment: @jdweng Didn't help :/ In my object catalog the file class is not mentioned [link](http://prntscr.com/al5tqc) Is this normal? :0

Comment: Try commenting out the Dictionary and see if you get a failure.  See following webpage : Connect 10MHz  input to Data Recorder (Figure 2) to output of 10MHz Phase Lock Source PLOC10-10.23-AC